# Different results for raw MD5 base64 encoded string between PHP and Clojure (Java) code for some characters

Tags: java, php, encoding, utf-8, clojure

I have a server that does create a hash using the following code:

```
base64_encode(md5("some value", true))
```

What I have to do is to produce the same hash value in Clojure (using Java interop). What I did is to create the following Clojure functions:

```
(defn md5-raw [s]
  (let [algorithm (java.security.MessageDigest/getInstance "MD5")
    size (* 2 (.getDigestLength algorithm))]
    (.digest algorithm (.getBytes s))))

(defn bytes-to-base64-string [bytes]
  (String. (b64/encode bytes) "UTF-8"))
```

Then I use that code that way:

```
(bytes-to-base64-string (md5-raw "some value")
```

Now, everything works fine with normal strings. However, after processing multiple different examples, I found the the following character is causing issues:

```
’
```

This is the `UTF-8` character `#8217`.

If I run the following `PHP` code:

```
base64_encode(md5("’", true))
```

What is returned is:

```
yOy9/y97p/GfapveLVQAHA==
```

If I run the following `Clojure` code:

```
(bytes-to-base64-string (md5-raw "’"))
```

I get the following value:

```
aF1ZConzUtEGRN2YXaKpoQ==
```

Why is that? I am suspecting a character encoding issue, but everything appears to be handled as UTF-8 as far as I can see.

Comment: First of all just remove base64, your problem in difference between md5-s.

Comment: @coredump thanks. However I did this such that we can see an actual string to compare. But I agree that this is an issue with md5.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not everything can be guaranteed to be UTF-8 in your example, the following expression depends on your default charset:

```
(.getBytes s)
```

You should - well, actually this depends on your use case - use:

```
(.getBytes s "UTF-8")
```

Demonstration:

```
(defn md5-with-charset
  [s charset]
  (let [algorithm (java.security.MessageDigest/getInstance "MD5")]
    (.digest algorithm (.getBytes s charset))))

(b64 (md5-with-charset "’" "UTF-8"))  ;; => "yOy9/y97p/GfapveLVQAHA=="
(b64 (md5-with-charset "’" "ASCII"))  ;; => "0UV7csP7MjomcRJa7z6rXQ=="
(b64 (md5-with-charset "’" "UTF-16")) ;; => "3CLVThylT2KkrocdUpxIpg=="
(b64 (md5-with-charset "’" "UTF-32")) ;; => "iHBMMMzkWTbPU+n8GCHitQ=="
```

(where `b64` is a base64 encoding step)

---

And I found it:

```
(b64 (md5-with-charset "’" "windows-1250")) ;; => "aF1ZConzUtEGRN2YXaKpoQ=="
```

Comment: wonderful, that was exactly my problem! Now I am forcing everything to be interpreted as UTF-8 on the Clojure side and everything is working as expected since everything is handled as UTF-8 on the PHP side.